Why this code work incorrect? What i do wrong?
please help me to understand.
This code doesn't work the way I think it should work.
What am I doing wrong? Add() method of A class return refference to newly created object in chlds vector. Then i call add() method on this newly created object, to add child to its chlds vector array.
obj.chlds = [A("a"), A("b"), A("c")],
objs.chlds[0].chlds = [A("xa")]
objs.chlds[1].chlds = [A("xb")]
objs.chlds[2].chlds = [A("xc")]

CODE:
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>



class A
{
    static int obj_cnt;
public:

    int id = 0;
    std::string ostr;
    std::vector<A> chlds;

    A(const A& _a)
    {
        ostr = _a.ostr;
        id = _a.id;
        chlds = _a.chlds;
        printf("\n A(const A&) : obj_cnt = %d, id = %d, name = %s", A::obj_cnt, id, ostr.c_str());
    }

    A(const char* str) : ostr(str)
    {
        id = A::obj_cnt++;
        printf("\n A(const char*): obj_cnt = %d, id = %d, name = %s", A::obj_cnt, id, ostr.c_str());
    }
    
    A& add(const char* str)
    {
        chlds.emplace_back(str);
        printf("\nin %s, chlds.size = %d", ostr.c_str(), chlds.size());
        return chlds.back();
    }
    
    ~A()
    {
        printf("\n~A(). id = %d, name = %s", id, ostr.c_str());
    }
};

int A::obj_cnt = 0;




int main()
{
    A obj("Container_1");
    obj.add("a").add("xa");
    obj.add("b").add("xb");
    obj.add("c").add("xc");
}

Console log:
 
 A(const char*): obj_cnt = 1, id = 0, name = Container_1
 A(const char*): obj_cnt = 2, id = 1, name = a
in Container_1, chlds.size = 1
 A(const char*): obj_cnt = 3, id = 2, name = xa
in a, chlds.size = 1
 A(const char*): obj_cnt = 4, id = 3, name = b
 A(const A&) : obj_cnt = 4, id = 2, name = xa
 A(const A&) : obj_cnt = 4, id = 1, name = a
~A(). id = 1, name = a
~A(). id = 2, name = xa
in Container_1, chlds.size = 2
 A(const char*): obj_cnt = 5, id = 4, name = xb
in b, chlds.size = 1
 A(const char*): obj_cnt = 6, id = 5, name = c
 A(const A&) : obj_cnt = 6, id = 2, name = xa
 A(const A&) : obj_cnt = 6, id = 1, name = a
 A(const A&) : obj_cnt = 6, id = 4, name = xb
 A(const A&) : obj_cnt = 6, id = 3, name = b
~A(). id = 1, name = a
~A(). id = 2, name = xa
~A(). id = 3, name = b
~A(). id = 4, name = xb
in Container_1, chlds.size = 3
 A(const char*): obj_cnt = 7, id = 6, name = xc
in c, chlds.size = 1

EXPECTATIONS:
obj.chlds = [A("a"), A("b"), A("c")], 
obj.chlds[0].chlds = [A("xa")] 
obj.chlds[1].chlds = [A("xb")],
obj.chlds[2].chlds = [A("xc")]

I cannot explain why this code creates COPY of "a" obj, and why object with name "xa" destroyed....
RESULT:
objs.childs[0] = [A("a")]
objs.childs[1] = [A("b")]
objs.childs[2] = [A("c")],
objs.chlds[0].chlds[0] = [], but shuld contain A("ax")
objs.chlds[1].chlds[0] = [], but shuld contain A("bx")
objs.chlds[2].chlds[0] = [A"cx")] !?


A(const A& _a) -- You failed to copy all of the members.  What about the chlds vector?  Also, one of the hardest bugs to find are ones where the copy constructor doesn't make complete copies, or has side effects (such as you adding 1 to id).  The copy constructors job is just that -- make copies, nothing more nothing less.  If you go against that, you better know exactly what you're doing and the issues that may come about by doing so.

A(const A& _a) : ostr(_a.ostr), id(_a.id), chlds(_a.chlds) { ++obj_cnt; printf("\n A(const A&) : obj_cnt = %d, id = %d, name = %s", A::obj_cnt, id, ostr.c_str()); } -- This is what I would expect the copy constructor (if you want to track things), should have been written.

Appending to a std::vector can cause the underlying array to grow, in which cases the objects in the array to be copied (or moved) to the new larger array. emplace_back will sometimes cause this (see "size" vs "capacity" of the vector).

Here is a demo which should give a hint of explanation: https://godbolt.org/z/xv3GvGMcK

Modernized version (C++23): https://godbolt.org/z/6Tfj5jTKM

Side note: "Add() method of A class" - There is no Add method in class A. There is however a method named add, but that's not the same thing. C++ is case sensitive.
